# Flutter app - google sign in no longer working

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm updating an old Flutter app of mine, and "Google Signin" no longer works.

I'm using

```
  firebase_ui_auth: ^1.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  firebase_ui_oauth_google: ^1.2.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.3.3
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.4
```

Here's the auth code...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().distinct(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // if not authenticated then show sign in screen
        if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
          return SignInScreen(
            // providers: providers,
            headerBuilder: (context, constraints, _) {
              return SignInHeader();
            },
          );
        }
        _checkEmailVerification();
        // as authenticated - show app main screen
        return _buildMainScreen();
      },
    );
  }
```

When I run this in the app I get the error...
"An unknown wrror occurred"

The IDE logging shows the following

```
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/DecorView(14185): [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
I/DecorView(14185): updateCaptionType >> DecorView@2cb9d4c[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
D/DecorView(14185): setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@2cb9d4c[]
I/DecorView(14185): getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=420 msg=resources_loaded
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@2cb9d4c TM=true
D/InputTransport(14185): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=132
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)0 dur=6 res=0x7 s={true 518689324656} ch=true fn=-1
D/OpenGLRenderer(14185): eglCreateWindowSurface
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11442 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4198 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2924 
D/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): Creating frameDrawingCallback nextDrawUseBlastSync=false reportNextDraw=true hasBlurUpdates=false
D/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): Creating frameCompleteCallback
D/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): Received frameDrawingCallback frameNum=1. Creating transactionCompleteCallback=false
D/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): Received frameCompleteCallback  lastAcquiredFrameNum=1 lastAttemptedDrawFrameNum=1
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$addFrameCompleteCallbackIfNeeded$3$ViewRootImpl:5000 android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): [DP] rdf()
D/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): reportDrawFinished (fn: -1) 
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputTransport(14185): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=147
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_STATUS_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity
I/FA      (14185): Application backgrounded at: timestamp_millis: 1689168021571
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_STATUS_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): stopped(false) old=false
I/DecorView(14185): notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.eis.lejog.lejog.MainActivity
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(14185): ensureControlAlpha: for ITYPE_STATUS_BAR on com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.eis.lejog.lejog.MainActivity
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)0 dur=4 res=0x1 s={true 518689751936} ch=false fn=2
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): updateBoundsLayer: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@49c75bf sc = Surface(name=Bounds for - com.eis.lejog.lejog/com.eis.lejog.lejog.MainActivity@1)/@0x9406a03 frame = 2
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): mWNT: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@49c75bf fN = 2 android.view.ViewRootImpl.prepareSurfaces:2783 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4029 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2924 
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): mWNT: merge t to BBQ
I/ViewRootImpl@eeb58b[MainActivity](14185): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager(14185): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(14185): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): stopped(true) old=false
D/OpenGLRenderer(14185): setSurface called with nullptr
D/OpenGLRenderer(14185): setSurface() destroyed EGLSurface
D/OpenGLRenderer(14185): destroyEglSurface
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport(14185): Input channel destroyed: '27c8e0a', fd=156
I/ViewRootImpl@5631977[SignInHubActivity](14185): handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=true visible=false
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: None of that logging shows any errors. I suggest doing some debugging to figure out which line of code causes the error, and get some more information about that error. Then update the question to show what you've found.

Comment: I can login with a user name/password, its only the Google Sign In that is failing. Thw error is occuring within the 'SignInScreen' code,  part of the "firebase_ui_auth" package, hence I'm not sure how to trace errors

Comment: Please edit the question to contain as much debugging information as you have.  Don't leave stuff buried in comments - they'll be easy to miss.